# 403 Forbidden for PDF download in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I have uploaded two files PDF and jpg in

```
wp-content/uploads/2014/05/one.pdf 
wp-content/uploads/2014/05/one.jpg
```

I can able to download the jpg file but not pdf. I even checked the .htaccess but there is not restriction in pdf file.

But I can able to download in localhost but not in my webhosting.

Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. In my case, and probably is the same for you, there was a .htaccess in the download folder (or one of the subfolders) that puts `deny from all`. Of course, that directive bans any user from accessing the folder.

You have two options in this case: (1) delete the .htacccess file alltogether or (2) set the permissions to whatever you need to.

Hope it helps.